# How to filter data Firebase and ionic

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm stuck with Firebase. I have added firebase^4.8.0 to my ionic project and am implementing a live chat.
I send the data from the sent message as follows.

```js
send(){
    this.datasend = {
        'sender': this.sessionData.mobile,
        'sendTo': this.data.id,
        'message': this.chatt,
    }

    this.chatt = '';

    firebase.database().ref('chats').push(this.datasend).then(res => {
         // logic here
    });
}
```

So far so good. I'm using the mobile number as the ID and when I send the data, I forward the message, the sender's mobile number and the recipient's mobile number. This works perfectly.

But I need to recover this data. I only need to show messages to the agent and recipient. I need to know how to make a filter for this.

I'm starting Firebase.

I'm currently stuck on this part.

```js
getmessages() {
    this.ref.on('value', data => {
        let tmp = [];
        date.forEach (date => {
            tmp.push ({
              'sender': data.val(). sender,
              'sendTo': data.val(). sendTo,
              'message': data.val(). message,
            })
        });
        this.messagesList = tmp;
    });
}
```

I just need to bring messages from the respective chat.
Any suggestions for a filter or other way to store messages that would help me solve this problem please.

Comment: You should use a ref like this `ref('chats/CHAT_ID/')`

Comment: Are you looking for how to filter data? If so, this would be a good place to start: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Comment: could you show me in practice? @HarshitRastogi

Answer (score 0):

I have created a `CHAT_ID` using the user id's of the respective users.
Suppose there are two users with ID's: 20 & 4, So i have created a chat id using these user ID's after sorting them `Math.min(20,4)`.

```
 const getMessages = () => {
    const CHAT_ID = Math.min(currentUser.id, otherUser.id)
    const chatref = 
    firebase.database().ref(`/chats/${CHAT_ID.toString()}`);
    chatref.off('value');
    chatref.on('value', chatsSnap => {
        const chatsArray = snapshotToArrayObject(chatsSnap);
        setStorage(`chats_${chatRoom.current}`, chatsArray);
        setChatMessages(chatsArray);
        scrollToRecentMessage();
        markAsRead();
    });
}
```

And When sending the message:

```
const sendMessage = () => {
   const messageArray = {
      to: otherUser.id,
      from: currentUser.id,
      message: newMessage,
      messageSeen: false,
      timeStamp: new Date()
   };
   const CHAT_ID = Math.min(currentUser.id, otherUser.id)
   firebase.database().ref(`/chats/${CHAT_ID.toString()}`)
                .push(messageArray);

}
```

Hope this might help you

Comment: Whaooooo!. Great idea. I will work this way. Thank you very much.

But just a note, the way you create the id is kind of peculiar. Math.min can create the same ID for other users. You should look for another way to create ID.

Thanks for the answer